# What possible values can environment variable take in Kubernetes container pod definition file?

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables

I have come across following yaml file in Kubernetes exercises from https://www.katacoda.com/courses/kubernetes/guestbook

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: php-redis
    image: gcr.io/google_samples/gb-frontend:v3
    env:
    - name: GET_HOSTS_FROM
      value: dns
      # If your cluster config does not include a dns service, then to
      # instead access environment variables to find service host
      # info, comment out the 'value: dns' line above, and uncomment the
      # line below.
      # value: env
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
```

Where can i find more info about environment variables values? What does „value: dns” mean? What are other possible values of that variable?

Comment: You would have to look at the code (or the documentation) for the `php-redis` container to see how the `GET_HOSTS_FROM` variable is used.

Comment: If it is not evaluated further shouldn't it be: "dns"?

Comment: Sure, that would be the *value* of the `GET_HOSTS_FROM` variable. But you were asking what that value means, and the answer to that depends entirely on the code running inside the container.

Comment: I get it but is there any difference between this two: 'value: dns' and 'value: "dns"' ?

Comment: No, there is no difference.